# httpClient error callback returns [object object] with status 500 internal server error in Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, nestjs, angular-httpclient

I want to thank you in advance for your help. I just uploaded an Angular + NestJS application to server. The users and emails and roles don't display in the html table. In the network tab and console I see 500 internal server error.
I consoled the error callback inside this.userService.subscribe() method so that it may help. But it only displays [object object].

It is so weird because the rest is working fine. I am able to login and logout, see profile data, and permission list, and register new user. On local server, emails and users displays properly and everything works as expected. Problem appears on live server!!

I also used Angular error handling and found that the error is basically from backend not Angular. Below is the returned error:

Backend returned code 500, body was: [object Object]

I have no idea about that error!
Does that mean the error is in NestJS? Maybe the Response Body is not proper JSON format?

[error appears on console tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JQsz.png)

[request/response detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrmO8.png)

endpoint for userService.ts is '/api/users'

```js
/* eslint-disable @nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries */
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-imports */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export abstract class RestService {
  abstract get endpoint(): string;

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {}

  all(page?: number): Observable<any> {
    let url = this.endpoint;
    if (page) {
      url += `?page=${page}`;
    }
    return this.http.get<any>(url);
  }
  

  create(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.endpoint, data);
  }

  sendEmail(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.endpoint, data);
  }

  get(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
  }

  update(id: number, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`, data);
  }

  delete(id: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`);
  }
}
```

users.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../../../interfaces/user';
import { ScrollService } from '../../../scroll.service';
import { MailerMailingListService } from '../../../services/mailer-mailing-list.service';
import { UserService } from '../../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'symbiota-dashboard-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css'],
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[] = [];
  emailList: string[] = [];
  page = 1;
  last_page!: number;
  checks = false;
  data = [];

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private mailerMailingListService: MailerMailingListService,
    private scrollService: ScrollService,
    public router: Router
  ) {}

  load(): void {
    this.userService.all(this.page).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.users = res.data;
      console.log(res.data);
      this.last_page = res.meta.last_page;
    });
  }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.load();
    //console.log('email list: ', this.emailList);
  }
  }
```

users.component.html

```js
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
          <td style="width: 2%">
            <!-- <input type="checkbox" [checked]="checks" /> -->
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              [checked]="checks"
              id="i"
              (click)="onSelect($event, '')"
            />
          </td>
          <td style="width: 2%">{{ user.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
          <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
          <td>will be added later</td>
          <td>{{ user.role.name }}</td>
          <td>
            <button
              class="btn-delete"
              style="background-color: #18976b"
              [routerLink]="['/dashboard/users', user.id, 'edit']"
            >
              Edit
            </button>
            <button
              class="btn-delete"
              style="background-color: rgb(226, 73, 73)"
              (click)="delete($event, user.id, i)"
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the return type of the data I get errors.
It is located in NestJS file. (user.service.ts)
I hope this helps that someone gives me a solution.

```js
async paginate(page = 1, relations = []): Promise<PaginatedResult> {
    const { data, meta } = await super.paginate(page, relations);

    return {
      data: data.map((user) => {
        const { password, ...data } = user;
        return data;
      }),
      meta,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the 500 error from the inspector? with request  and response headers & body. You sure that the URL or the URL formatting is correct

Comment: I was not able to add the image itself but I just added link to image of console tab.

Comment: I also added the request/response detail link

Comment: Well everything works complete fine with local host but the live version does not work for some path. /api/users , /api/emails and /api/roles.  I thought that get method is blocked in server but when I visit /api/roles/create it lists all the permissions - which is also a get request!

Comment: You sure that nginx is configured correctly? Did you try the request with postman or any other means? You can bypass ufw and try requesting with postman directly to the ip address/api/users.

Comment: Also debug the server req or log it. see the baseUrl prop on the req. Verify if the req is in the expected format

Comment: I tried with postman and got the same thing.

Comment: honestly, I don't know enough about proper nginx configuration for Angular/nestjs application.

Comment: how should I debug the server req?

Comment: The Angular and NestJS application is inside Nx monorepo. All the coding and logic are in libs folder. Does that help?

Comment: I am using plesk as cpanel. Under Apache and nginx setting: proxy mode, smart static files processing, and serve static files directly by nginx check boxes are checked.

Comment: If it is a database related configuration issue or server, so why I am able to login and register! Why I get list of permissions from db! The same Abstract service works for permissions but not for users and emails which all works well in local host!

Comment: Using error handling in Angular I found that it is related to backend not the Angular.
returned code:

Backend returned code 500, body was: [object Object]